# JavaScript Image upload function and calling it from another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function which gets called on a click of a button.As soon as the button is clicked I want to call the image upload function and then this image should get appended to my previous function

JavaScript Code

```js
var gridster;
var $color_picker = $('#color_picker');

gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
  widget_base_dimensions: [100, 100],
  widget_margins: [5, 5],
  helper: 'clone',
  resize: {
    enabled: true
  }
}).data('gridster');

$('.gridster').on("click", ".delete-button", function() {
  gridster.remove_widget($(this).parent());
});

$(".add-button").on("click", function() {

  // get selected color value
  var color = $color_picker.val();

  // build the widget, including a class for the selected color value
  var $widget = $('<li>', {
      'class': 'color_' + color
    })
    .append($('<button>', {
      'class': 'delete-button',
      'text': '-'
    }))
    .append($(Some image appending
      function()));

  // add widget to the grid
  gridster.add_widget($widget, 1, 1);

});



Image appending function() {

  should open a dialog box where user can upload image

  return image uploaded by user

}
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/tyL47pqm/8/)

I tried with this  [File Upload Code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) but this doesnt seem to fit my case

Any help will be really appreciated.